# Response time for the tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It would be nice to have a feature in SO which calculates the response time for each tags. Something like, question tagged with PHP- 27 seconds, Python- 10 seconds ( not so fast as I know though :)) Does somebody know anything about it?

Comment: Like, questions tagged x get their first answer in 17 seconds on average, questions tagged y in 23 hours?

Comment: Exactly, added your comments in question.

Comment: What would be the value of such a feature?

Comment: It should be possible to write such a query in the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), though I haven't seen anything like this yet.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to see how SO is doing WRT other sites?

Comment: That one's a non-starter, @Jack. As we all know, the procedure to answer questions on other sites is: 1. copy question to Stack Overflow, 2. get answer, 3. rephrase and post as answer to original.

Comment: I think it best to go for quality answers rather than fast ones

Comment: It should be easy enough to whip up something in [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/54790/time-to-answer) that would tell you this.

Comment: "PHP questions are answered faster on [so]... We'll write the application in PHP" ;)

Comment: @Lix - Great heuristic for selecting tech... I will end up with PHP on iOS using Oracle and jQuery. For my Android devices.

Answer (score 8):

On SE sites the emphasis is on the quality of answers which is evaluated by the community in the form of voting up and accepting answers.

The speed at which answers are supplied is irrelevant, it is the quality/correctness that matters. I can see the interest in such a metric, but I think it would encourage [TFGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) syndrome and detract from the overall quality of answers.

I typed this in 1m 22.3777s

Comment: Not fast enough :(

Comment: I'm practicing, and be fair, I did have to find the link :)